# OAuth2 globally defined client & concurrent backend function execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I have some confusion about integrating OAuth 2 flow (Google APIs) into my app. I have declared a Oauth2 client variable (globally) as shown below:

```
const {gapi} = require('googleapis');
var auth2;

/**
 * Initializes the Sign-In client.
 */
var initClient = function() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function(){
        /**
         * Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the
         * client.
         */
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        });

        // Attach the click handler to the sign-in button
        auth2.attachClickHandler('signin-button', {}, onSuccess, onFailure);
    });
};
```

If I were to use Google Calendar API, I would do this:

```
const doSomethingWithGCalendar = (token) => {
    auth2.setCredentials({
       access_token: token
    });
        
    const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth: auth2});
// Execute some actions here
}
```

I am confused about how node.js handles this. After all, the `auth2` client variable is globally declared (I picture in my head as one, single instance). However, there will be multiple users using my app, so the line  `.setCredentials` and subsequent Google Calendar API calls will run, probably in multiple threads and concurrently, I'm assuming.

They should be running concurrently in the node.js server, but they're using the same globally declared variable `auth2`. How would that work ?

Should I, instead, declare a local variable inside `doSomethingWithGCalendar()` like this:

```
const doSomethingWithGCalendar = (token) => {
    const auth2 = new OAuth2Client(
        {client_id: 'CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com'}
    );
    // Set Credentials/tokens and then run Google Calendar API operations ...
```